# Indexing last number of a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have a JSON object, here it is:

```
{
    "868": {
        "header": "New limited",
        "lite": "1337 Gaming Headset",
        "icon": "",
        "items": { "Stock": "1,337", "Price": "R$750" },
        "extra": { "product": 25355494 },
        "url": "",
        "id": 868,
        "added": 1438542256903
    },
    "869": {
        "header": "New Face",
        "lite": "Furious George",
        "icon": "",
        "items": { "Price": "R$200" },
        "extra": { "product": 25355932 },
        "url": "",
        "id": 869,
        "added": 1438543456863
    },
    "870": {
        "header": "Almost sold out",
        "lite": "1337 Gaming Headset",
        "icon": "",
        "items": { "Stock": "1,337", "Remaining": "133", "Price": "R$750" },
        "extra": { "product": 25355494 },
        "url": "",
        "id": 870,
        "added": 1438544588831
    },
    "871": {
        "header": "Sold out",
        "lite": "1337 Gaming Headset",
        "icon": "",
        "items": { "Price": "R$750" },
        "extra": { },
        "url": "",
        "id": 871,
        "added": 1438544704049
    },
    "872": {
        "header": "New Hat",
        "lite": "Elite Spy Eye",
        "icon": "",
        "items": { "Price": "R$250" },
        "extra": { "product": 25356879 },
        "url": "",
        "id": 872,
        "added": 1438545677167
    }
}
```

I want to know how to index the last thing of this json object. I can't describe it any more but it might be the key.

I want to basically index the last object in the object, so that would be the bit where it says `"872":{"header":"New Hat"` near the bottom

So basically it's the biggest number I want to index. I already tried to index the last one with `[4]` as an index but it came up with undefined.

Comment: "the last object in the object" Keys in an object have not any specific order, hence the question is more or less meaningless. If you want to "order" keys, use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the keys in an object.

Comment: @Teemu: Read the last line: _"So basically it's the biggest number I want to index."_ That is do-able.

Comment: @josephmichael Just [reminding](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) ...

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that you might want this:

```js
var str = '{"868":{"header":"New limited","lite":"1337 Gaming Headset","icon":"","items":{"Stock":"1,337","Price":"R$750"},"extra":{"product":25355494},"url":"","id":868,"added":1438542256903},"869":{"header":"New Face","lite":"Furious George","icon":"","items":{"Price":"R$200"},"extra":{"product":25355932},"url":"","id":869,"added":1438543456863},"870":{"header":"Almost sold out","lite":"1337 Gaming Headset","icon":"","items":{"Stock":"1,337","Remaining":"133","Price":"R$750"},"extra":{"product":25355494},"url":"","id":870,"added":1438544588831},"871":{"header":"Sold out","lite":"1337 Gaming Headset","icon":"","items":{"Price":"R$750"},"extra":{},"url":"","id":871,"added":1438544704049},"872":{"header":"New Hat","lite":"Elite Spy Eye","icon":"","items":{"Price":"R$250"},"extra":{"product":25356879},"url":"","id":872,"added":1438545677167}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(str);

var last = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(b) - parseInt(a);
})[0]; // suppose to be "872" in this case

console.log('"' + last + '": ' + JSON.stringify(obj[last]));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var json = {
                "868": {
                    "header": "New limited",
                    "lite": "1337 Gaming Headset",
                    "icon": "",
                    "items": { "Stock": "1,337", "Price": "R$750" },
                    "extra": { "product": 25355494 },
                    "url": "",
                    "id": 868,
                    "added": 1438542256903
                },
                "869": {
                    "header": "New Face",
                    "lite": "Furious George",
                    "icon": "",
                    "items": { "Price": "R$200" },
                    "extra": { "product": 25355932 },
                    "url": "",
                    "id": 869,
                    "added": 1438543456863
                },
                "870": {
                    "header": "Almost sold out",
                    "lite": "1337 Gaming Headset",
                    "icon": "",
                    "items": { "Stock": "1,337", "Remaining": "133", "Price": "R$750" },
                    "extra": { "product": 25355494 },
                    "url": "",
                    "id": 870,
                    "added": 1438544588831
                },
                "871": {
                    "header": "Sold out",
                    "lite": "1337 Gaming Headset",
                    "icon": "",
                    "items": { "Price": "R$750" },
                    "extra": {},
                    "url": "",
                    "id": 871,
                    "added": 1438544704049
                },
                "872": {
                    "header": "New Hat",
                    "lite": "Elite Spy Eye",
                    "icon": "",
                    "items": { "Price": "R$250" },
                    "extra": { "product": 25356879 },
                    "url": "",
                    "id": 872,
                    "added": 1438545677167
                }
            }
            var keys = Object.keys(json);
            var last = keys[keys.length - 1];
            document.write('"' + last + '": ' + JSON.stringify(json[last]));
```